# Invoking Java classes passed as a parameter to main method

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I want to write a main method that does some generic setup (opens input and output streams), and then invokes a static method in another class that is passed to it as a run-time argument. How do I achieve this?

Comment: By coding, compiling, and executing it.

Comment: Are you asking about how to invoke a (static) method using its name provided as String, i.e using Reflection?

Comment: Exactly, the name of the class (which is unknown at compile-time) is passed to the main method as part of its args[] array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume both the name of the class and the method to call are passed as arguments.

You load the class using [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-), which will give you a `Class` instance for it.

You get a `Method` instance for the method using [`Class#getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-), passing in an array of appropriate `Class` instances to identify the signature,  or [`Class#getMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) and looking through the resulting array.

You *call* the method using [`Method#invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-).

You'll find lots of information about doing this in the [`Class` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and the [`java.lang.Reflection` package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

Comment: +1 for not feeding the vampires